# In Designer: Property default value is set, but property isn't called while setting default?

Tags: c#, attributes, properties, designer

I have a piece of code that goes something like this:

```
[DefaultValue(false)]
public bool Property
{
    set
    {
        blah = value;
        someControl.Visible = value;
    }
    get
    {
        return blah;
    }
}
```

When I look at the properties in the designer, the property is set to false (or true if I play with it).
But the property isn't actually set. The **Visible** value of the control isn't changed.

How can I make the designer actually set the property with the default value ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [DefaultValue] attribute is only a hint to the designer and the serializer.  It is completely up to you to ensure that the default value you promised in the attribute is in fact the value of the property.  The property setter doesn't get called in your case because the serializer detected that the current value of the property equals the default value and can thus *omit* the property assignment.  It is an optimization, it makes InitializeComponent() smaller and faster.

You ensure this simply by initializing the property value in your constructor.  Beware that a control's Visible property defaults to true.

Answer (score 1):

Two options;

- take away the default (bool defaults to false anyway)
- use ShouldSerialize* to make it clear

in the latter, you might want a bool? to track "explicit set" vs "implicit default":

```
private bool? property;
public bool Property
{
    set
    {
        property = value;
        someControl.Visible = value;
    }
    get
    {
        return property.GetValueOrDefault();
    }
}
public void ResetProperty() { property = null; }
public bool ShouldSerializeProperty() { return property.HasValue; }
```

Note that Reset* and ShouldSerialize* are patterns recognized by the component-model.

Comment: I do want the property to have the default value. I would just like the designer to actually call the property, instead of just setting it false (So the control's visibility will change). At run time it seems to work OK, and the default value with the control's visibility as well.

Comment: @Yochai - the combination of Reset* and ShouldSerialize* should operate *like* the default, but allowing explicit control.

Comment: 1. The bool default is false, but visible default is true. So I need it set to false. 2.I could also just call this.Propery = flase; in the InitializeComponent() ...

Comment: @Yochai - yes, for that you'll need to set visible to false at some point; DefaultValue *never* causes things to get set - it only impacts things like serialization. It it your job to make what it claims correct.

Comment: But I want it to be set in one place. How will I set call the property according to the default value set in the attribute ? (So when someone changes the default, the visibility will change programaticly?)

Comment: @Yochai How will the default change? Besides, if you aren't using DefaultAttribute, the default is whatever your code sets it to...?

Comment: It's a design issue, it's not an issue of what I do. In the future if someone decides that the default needs to change, it should change where it is declared. (in one single place)

Comment: @Yochai - changing a default value is breaking an implicit contract. You can get around that by never treating it as a default, so clients always set it as desired; but then you need for forget thinking about it as a default. Which it isn't, if you need to design around changing it.