# Where to save configuration file for dll in GAC - Best Practice

Tags: c#, visual-studio, config

I have a set of dlls that are stored in GAC, 'cause I have to use it both at designtime and runtime. One of these dlls get some info from an `App.Config` file. What is the best place to store this file, so that it can be loaded both at designtime and runtime?

Comment: Do these settings apply globally to all uses of the DLL, or are they per-user, or are they per-application?  Ex: If First.EXE uses your dll and Second.exe uses your DLL, do you want the configuration changes shared?

Comment: the settings are the same for every use of the dll. So first.EXE and second.EXE will have the same settings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want the changes to be shared across all EXEs that use the DLL, you do not want to use an app.config.  Every exe has it's own App.config so the settings would be remembered per-executable.  Instead, use the project ["Settings"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx) option.

Right click on your DLL project and go to Properties.  Then pick the "Settings" tab and click the link to create a settings file.  This will create a .settings file.  These default values are compiled into your application so there is nothing in the app.config files.  Settings can be read and updated and are saved in the user's directory

Put your default settings in there.  You can get to them by accessing YourProjectName.Settings.Default.SettingName.  You can change them then call YourProjectName.Settings.Default.Save.

Comment: I do not understand why -1. This seems to be a correct way to solve the problem.

Comment: And it has been accepted as the answer! Obsessive downvoting spoils this site.

Answer (score 3):

A DLL (or Class Library in C# terms) does **NOT** have an App.config file. An Application has an App.config (or web.config if website).

The DLLs can access the application's configuration information but they don't themselves have config files. The whole point of a DLL is that is can be used by many different applications and does not have configuration itself. Instead its "host" will contain the configuration information, so this is "by design".

Comment: hmmm...ok. But the problem is that I have to use this dll in Visual Studio (it provides deisgn time data access functionalities). So, where I have to store information about settings, so that the same information will be used at runtime too?

Comment: @Riccardo You should put all your settings in `App.config` which after compilation is generated as `[AppName].exe.config` and put in same folder as executable.

Comment: @Riccardo Are you looking for [DefaultValue] attribute? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367441/in-designer-property-default-value-is-set-but-property-isnt-called-while-sett?rq=1 This can determine what the default values are for a control at design-time.