# WinForms Designer deos not save overridden property that his default value is the parent value

Tags: c#, properties, attributes, overriding, windows-forms-designer

Why if I override property that his default value is the parent value the designer does not save the value in the designer.cs?

I found these sources below and tried any DesignerSerializationVisibility but still can't to solves it.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5368954/9127498
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3135428/9127498

Code:

```
    public partial class CustomGroupBox : GroupBox
    {
        private RightToLeft rightToLeft = RightToLeft.Inherit;
        public override RightToLeft RightToLeft
        {
            get
            {
                return rightToLeft == RightToLeft.Inherit ? this.Parent != null ? this.Parent.RightToLeft : RightToLeft.No : rightToLeft;
            }
            set
            {
                if ((int)value < (int)RightToLeft.No || (int)value > (int)RightToLeft.Inherit)
                    throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("RightToLeft", (int)value, typeof(RightToLeft));
                RightToLeft old = this.RightToLeft;
                rightToLeft = value;
                if (this.RightToLeft != old)
                    base.OnRightToLeftChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Why if I override property that his default value is the parent value the designer does not save the value in the designer.cs?` Can you talk us through **how** you are overriding it? In code (and if so, in which file)?

Comment: @mjwills I created a new CustomGroupBox Class and I had to rewrite the RIghtToLeft Property, I did it by looking at the microsoft .net reference source and everything runs well but I found the designer not really save (set) this property at the designer.cs file of the parent form. Please see the edited code.